# Numpy array: concatenate arrays and integers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, integer, concatenation

In my Python program I concatenate several integers and an array. It would be intuitive if this would work:

```
x,y,z = 1,2,np.array([3,3,3])
np.concatenate((x,y,z))
```

However, instead all ints have to be converted to np.arrays:

```
x,y,z = 1,2,np.array([3,3,3])
np.concatenate((np.array([x]),np.array([y]),z))
```

Especially if you have many variables this manual converting is tedious. The problem is that x and y are 0-dimensional arrays, while z is 1-dimensional. Is there any way to do the concatenation without the converting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They just have to be sequence objects, not necessarily numpy arrays:

```
x,y,z = 1,2,np.array([3,3,3])
np.concatenate(([x],[y],z))
# array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Numpy also does have an `insert` function that will do this:

```
x,y,z = 1,2,np.array([3,3,3])
np.insert(z, [0,0], [x, y])
```

I'll add that if you're just trying to add integers to an list, you don't need numpy to do it:

```
x,y,z = 1,2,[3,3,3]
z = [x] + [y] + z
```

or

```
x,y,z = 1,2,[3,3,3]
[x, y] + z
```

or

```
x,y,z = 1,2,[3,3,3]
z.insert(0, y)
z.insert(0, x)
```

Comment: Heh, this makes me feel a little bit stupid :). Thanks for your help. Now I also understand that there is a difference between ints/floats and sequence types like lists,tuples etc.